# Typescript - Pushing values from one array to another outputs integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I've come across some strange behavior that I cannot find the root cause of when pushing the contents of one string array to another.

I have one array that I first empty to make room for the new array's values and then I iterate over the new array, pushing its contents to the first emptied array. Here is how the code looks:

```
oldArray.length = 0;
console.log(newArray);
for (let item in newArray) {
  console.log(item);
  this.oldArray.push(item);
}
```

The output of the first print is:

```
["a string", "another string", "a third string"]
```

The output of each print inside the for loop is:

```
0, 1, 2
```

This is where I am lost, I am for some reason getting the indexes of the items instead of the strings themselves. Could it be related to the way in which I am emptying the old array? Note that for this purpose, it's important that I do not mess up the oldArray reference, which I'd prefer to keep intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `for( .. in ..)`, you iterate over the indexes of the array, not the values themselves. To get the value, you could do this:

```
console.log(newArray[item]);
```

It's even better to just use the `for(.. of ..)` loop instead.

```
for (const item of newArray) {
```

Aside: use `const` instead of `let` for this case.

Comment: That's exactly it! I was very confused since it seemingly worked in another place, but there I was using 'of' and not 'in'...